# Error importing to SQL Server 2008R2 from Excel 2010

Tags: sql, database, excel, import

I am using the SQL Server Import and Export Wizard to try to import a particular xlsx spreadsheet into an existing table in SQL.  The existing table contains a sub-set of the columns in the spreadsheet and I am ignoring the many columns that don't match.

The spreadsheet has 123 columns and 238 lines of data.

Initially when I was importing the spreadsheet the wizard was hanging on 'Executing' and I had to kill the process.   Something I have never come across before.

After copy and pasting the data into a new spreadsheet it is now coming up with the following error:

> > Error 0xc020901c: Data Flow Task 1: There was an error with output column "Confidentiality Clause Comments" (108) on output "Excel Source Output" (9). The column status returned was: "Text was truncated or one or more characters had no match in the target code page.".
> >      (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
> >
> > Error 0xc020902a: Data Flow Task 1: The "output column "Confidentiality Clause Comments" (108)" failed because truncation occurred, and the truncation row disposition on "output column "Confidentiality Clause Comments" (108)" specifies failure on truncation. A truncation error occurred on the specified object of the specified component.
> >      (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

What I am confused about it, the column "Confidentiality Clause Comments" is one of the columns being ignored - it is not being imported into the database!

I have tried setting "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Jet 4.0\Engines\Excel\TypeGuessRows" to both 0 and higher numbers like 238 and 1000 to increase the sample size.  (Although the table does already exist with fields large enough for the data being imported).  I also have the "On Truncation (global)" and "On Error (global)" set to Ignore (but this setting seems to be 'ignored').

I have also tried importing the data into a new table, and get the same truncation error message (but on different fields dependant on the data sort).

I thought about importing as a CSV file but there are embedded comma's in many of the fields and it completely messed the data up.

Any ideas on how to get data imported?  I have spent over 3 hours on this already, and have got nowhere.

Thanks,Steve

Answer (score 0):

Instead of CSV, you could save as `Text (Tab delimited) (*.txt)` - that way you won't encounter the comma problem.

Also, if you only need to do this once, and because the dataset is not exactly huge, I'd consider just copying from excel and pasting directly into sql server management studio.

Comment: Thanks Paul, but looks like there are tabs as well embedded as for some of the rows as the data gets messed up for around 10 rows of data.

Comment: Out of the 123 columns of data I am trying to import about 50 columns of data which are randomly spread throughout.

Comment: @Steve, I'd just copy the columns I wanted to a new sheet, then move them around till they matched the table definition, then ctrl-c, ctrl-v. Of course this approach is not suitable for a job that you want to schedule to happen again and again.

Comment: I may have to do that as I am stuck for what else to do - and hope this import is a one off!